# Reviewing text of scheduled job - Transact SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using only VS2012 Ultimate Server Xplorer Pane to code and execute my job. I used to add a job scheduling to perform some task at specific time.

Now that I realize my executed command implemented is incorrect. I can delete this by making another new query on the database then recreate a new similar job but I don't want to do this.

I don't know how to fix the command text.

Answer (score 0):

Get Management Studio, and stop trying to do this through Visual Studio.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43351

Download SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe (unless you are on x86 for some reason, in which case pick the other one). It's ~1GB, not sure why, sorry about that.

Starting with 2012 SP1, Management Studio Express is fully functional with no license requirement (this is the first time this has happened).

Connect to your server, expand SQL Server Agent > Jobs, and double-click your job. Nice enough UI that will let you edit steps, schedules, etc. without doing any of this hokey generate-an-entire-script-for-a-job stuff...

Comment: Ok thank you, I am deleting the previous version of MSSQLmanagement studio and downloading this 11.0.3xx

Comment: By the way, I found that I saved the file xxx.sql which stores my command text in my project folder too. I now can open and edit it too.